# Is it possible to create an event listener for the definition of a specific global variable?

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener

I have some code that relies on a global variable: `window.Raven`. It's created by a script that's loaded asynchronously.

I was wondering if there's a way to listen for when this global variable is defined, so that I can queue and replay any actions that need this global variable until after it's defined (using a callback isn't possible in my context unfortunately).

Comment: Neither can you use a jQuery `deferred`? If so I think one option (unreliable one) would be to put a timeout until your variable is defined, and calculate how much time you'd need for it to finish.

Comment: Sorry, but it would be overkill to add jquery to my bundle for that.

Comment: a decent setInterval?

Comment: @mehulmpt If there's no other way that could be a solution, but I was hoping for a more precise method

Comment: Well event dispatcher or observer is legitimate solution for this kind of thing but as you explicitly declared that callback is not possible so setInterval may come in rescue

Comment: I think more something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Comment: Or javascript Proxy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Answer (score -1):

[according this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events)

you should put

```js
var elem = document;//other
//// Listen for the event.
elem.addEventListener('building', function (e) {
  alert("fire event");
}, false);
document.getElementById("click").onclick=function(){
  // Create the event.
  var event = new Event('building');
  //var event = new CustomEvent('build', { 'detail': elem.dataset.time });
  // Dispatch the event.
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

```html
<button id="click">like async</button>
```